# Image jumping out of table randomly on different loads?

Tags: html

i am currently at college studying web design and devolpment, i am working on my portfolio and creating a website for someone, (unfinished) if you go to this link.

http://www.mattwoodsfitnessandweightloss.co.uk/

and randomly click a few links [ Home page / About / Our Studio ] multiple times etc you will notice the "about matt woods" sometimes jumps out of the table or completley dissapears all together, i didnt notice it on Firefox because it dosent happen but checked on IE and it seems to only happen on IE, its also happening on a friends IE so its not just mine.

**EDIT:** here are some screenshots:
[image: error1]
[image: error2]

Can anyone help?

Cheers.

Comment: IE9 and Opera 10 show no errors. IE9 Shows no erroneous behaviour in either normal and comaptibility view.

Comment: IE 8 as i am using XP and can not get 9(Vista/7)

Comment: i've experienced similar behavior on my site with firefox 3.16. haven't found a solution at all, it seem'd like the parser sometimes parse wrong.

Comment: I just saw that behaviour on my IE8. It seems that this is some special behaviour caused by the rendering engine of IE8. The thing is that if i "mark" the row with the links "home,about ...." then it suddenly appears on the right place without a reload of the page

Comment: Compatibility view in that same IE8 doesn't show any problems so i guess that they switch the rendering engine when you switch from normal to compatibility view.

Answer (score 0):

Different browser's render the padding and width of the html element differently. so if you want a consistent look across all the browser you should consider adding a reset style sheet to your page.

Download the following stylesheet [Download](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) and add it to your webpage.